# Facebook instant game specific URL sharing problem

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-instant-articles, facebook-instant-games

I  created specific url's for Instant game by getting parameters, for example:

fb.gg/play/Myappid/5

So 5 is parameter is this case, when 5 is called, I showing some specific content to the user in Instant Game, but my problem is that I want to post this specific URL to the Facebook, when I am doing that, it's not showing a picture of this link, I see other Facebook Pages which posting similar links, but their Image works  ( Problem is that when I am trying to post  the same link fb.gg/theirappid/theirparameter, its  not showing image also, but link is working like mine, so wondering if there is any possibility to post a link of instant game which will also show the image to Facebook users?

Comment: You would have to tell us what URL you have a problem with for us to tell you what you are doing wrong

Comment: For example, https://fb.gg/play/syndromy/555  this link will open you some of the app inside instant game, so not main page. thats what I want, but problam is that when I share this link to the page, it does not showing clickable image on facebook, it just empty image.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/lllolll.lol/posts/2179898602275565  , Thats how I want to post instant game url, but it does not posting Image in my case

Comment: I tested this and it should be showing the App Video you have uploaded in the developer dashboard. If you have not uploaded a video, perhaps it will not show up.

Comment: And how this LOL is uploading  on page  specific LINK of instant game with picture? I mean clickable picture exactly as it is on page I linked. can you check it ?  I wan't to do exactly the same thing, but no success.